# Insert image to a folder in a web method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, file-upload

As part of my web method I am trying to save an image to a folder. The folder name is in the root and it's called 'images'. In the web method I find my html control fileupload and try save the picture but it keeps giving the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
fuClubLogo was null.
```

I do not understand why it keeps bring back null.

Here is my code

HTML

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuClubLogo" class="form-control" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="btnSaveClub" class="itg-btn news-btn" runat="server" Text="Save"/>
```

C#

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string SaveUpdateClub(string ClubName, string Email, string Password, string ClubLogoName)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
        WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[tb_ClubDetails] where ClubID = @ClubID", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClubID", ClubName);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            result = "A club with this name already exists.";
            con.Close();
            dr.Close();
        }
        else
        {
        //Here I make an attempt to save the image to a folder
            Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
            FileUpload fuClubLogo = (FileUpload)page.FindControl("fuClubLogo");

            string imgFile = Path.GetFileName(fuClubLogo.PostedFile.FileName);
            fuClubLogo.PostedFile.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/images/") + imgFile);

            SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(
            WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ConnectionString);
            con2.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("sp_insertupdateClub", con2);
            cmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClubID", "");
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClubName", ClubName);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClubEmail", Email);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClubPassword", Password);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClubLogoImage", ClubLogoName);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogoImagePath", "/images/" + ClubLogoName);

            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con2.Close();
            result = "The club details are saved.";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSaveClub").click(function () {
        var ClubName = $("#txtClubName").val();
        var Email = $("#txtEmail").val();
        var Password = $("#txtPassword").val();
        var ClubLogoName = $("#fuClubLogo").val().split('\\').pop();



        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AddViewClub.aspx/SaveUpdateClub",
            data: "{'ClubName': '" + ClubName +
                "','Email': '" + Email +
                "','Password': '" + Password +
                "','ClubLogoName': '" + ClubLogoName + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                //document.getElementById("Label10").innerHTML = response.d;
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I have also tried to upload the image to the folder by using Ajax Jquery but I could not achieve that, that is why I am trying to do it from the web method.

Please assist and advise. Thank you.

Comment: You can not access page controls inside static web methods. You can use `AsyncFileUpload` ajax toolkit control. http://www.ajaxtoolkit.net/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx

Comment: Thank you. Could you please give me more information how to approach this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot access to page controls in webservice.

1) create a fileupload handler that will return filename.

```
public class FileUploadHandler : IHttpHandler
{

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";
        HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[0];
        string path = context.Server.MapPath("~/images/" + filename);
        file.SaveAs(path);

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(filename);
    }

}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

2) call upload handler then save to database

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnSaveClub").click(function () {
    UploadImage();
    return false;
});

var filename;
function UploadImage() {
    var fileUpload = $("#fuClubLogo").get(0);
    var files = fileUpload.files;

    var data = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "FileUploadHandler.ashx",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            filename = result;
            SaveToDb();
        },
        error: function (err) {
        }
    });
}

function SaveToDb() {
    var ClubName = $("#txtClubName").val();
    var Email = $("#txtEmail").val();
    var Password = $("#txtPassword").val();
    var ClubLogoName = filename;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AddViewClub.aspx/SaveUpdateClub",
        data: "{'ClubName': '" + ClubName +
            "','Email': '" + Email +
            "','Password': '" + Password +
            "','ClubLogoName': '" + ClubLogoName + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            //document.getElementById("Label10").innerHTML = response.d;
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: I get the following error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) FileUploadHandler.ashx:1

Comment: did you create a handler named "FileUploadHandler.ashx" in your project directory?

Comment: Yes. I copied it directly from here.

Comment: could you send screenshot of your project directory in visual studio?

Comment: Just to make sure, is there a specific place to put the FileUploadHandler.ashx" handle in my aspx.cs page?

Comment: not in your page. create handler by Add -> Add New Item ->  search for handler and name it "FileUploadHandler.ashx"

Comment: It is working now! The mistake I made was, I added a ASP.NET handler. I was suppose to add a Generic Handler. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just a question to clarify something...I only noticed now. When my picture saves into the image folder it gets renamed to a random name, is there a reason for this?

Comment: it's only to prevent the errors you can face when a file with same name already exists. if you prefer to upload with same name you can, but first check whether file with that name doesn't exist.